# Forcing Windows XP to use external monitor without GUI

Tags: windows-xp, external-display

I've got a laptop with a dead LCD martrix.  I can connect an external monitor, and this displays the windows 'loading' screen fine.  However, when windows has started the screen is blank (no signal), and fn-F4 does not do anything.

**Is there any other way of forcing XP to use the external monitor, that does not require configuration via the GUI?**

Additional info:
I get a signal in XP safe mode.

Comment: Is the screen blank as in "you only see the extended desktop" or in "the screen receives no signal"?

Comment: @oliver: Screen receives no signal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> (opens Start menu)
2. Press <kbd>C</kbd> (Selects Control Panel)
3. Press <kbd>D</kbd> (Selects Date and Time)
4. Press <kbd>D</kbd> (Selects Display)
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Opens the Display Properties dialog)
6. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (Selects the tab control)
7. Press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> 4 times (Selects the Settings tab)
8. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> 2 times (Selects the Display dropdown box)
9. Press <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> (Selects second display in said dropdown and focuses on the display arrangement panel)
10. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> 4 times (Focuses the *Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor* checkbox)
11. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> (Checks the checkbox)
12. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (The display should now activate)
13. At this point it is very likely that you will be asked if the selected configuration is working correctly (remember the dialog?). Pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> should confirm the dialog.

This works only if you're already logged on and are using an English version of Windows XP.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  Although I had to modify steps 1-5, as this only works if you don't have any other programs beginning with c in your start men. 1. Win-R to bring up run dialog, 2. type 'control desk.cpl' enter, to open screen properties. From then on follow step 6 onwards.